# Can't play QuickTime RLE in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, video, totem, quicktime

I frequently create videos from png sequences using `avconv` by running:

```
avconv -r 24 -i images%6d.png -vcodec qtrle video.mov
```

Since I've upgraded to 14.04 I cannot play back them any more. Not with `totem`, not with `mplayer`.

`totem` show only the first frame, and nothing happens when I press play.

`mplayer` reports:

```
Dropping frame with size not matching configured size
Too many buffered pts
```

Same videos play fine with `totem` on 13.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that support is included in Ubuntu Restricted Extras available for installation through the software center.

It seems like something went awry with mplayer between svn36171 and svn36210.

source:  http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/mplayer-users/2013-May/086267.html

Try playing with Xine

Comment: xine works, mplayer svn37182 too.

Comment: Installing Ubuntu Restricted Extras doesn't help totem.

Comment: @shinjin As I recall totem uses gstreamer plugins